# $? returns errorlevel 0 instead of 4

Tags: shell, error-handling

I just migrated a working Windows Batch script (.bat) to Unix Shell. Generally it's working quite nicely, however, I just realized that the errorlevel that is returned in Unix is wrong.

From what I've read, the `%errorlevel%` command from Windows "translates" to `$?` in Unix. However, the Windows Batch script used to return an errorlevel of 4 when an error occured during the execution of the Java application called within the script.

Unix `$?` returns 0 instead of 4, which causes my automated error check to interpret the actually faulty application run as a success.

How can I make Unix return the proper errorlevel? From what I could gather it should actually return values > 0 when an error occurs...

Here's my shell script:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java"
EXECUTABLE="my.java.executable"

BASEDIR=`dirname $0`
cd $BASEDIR

LOCAL_CP=$BASEDIR

for f in `find $BASEDIR/lib -type f -name "*.jar"` `find $BASEDIR/lib -type f -name "*.zip"`
do
  LOCAL_CP=$LOCAL_CP:$f
done

# various variables being assigned

VMARGS="-various -vmargs -assigned -here"

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java $VMARGS -cp $LOCAL_CP $EXECUTABLE $various_variables

echo $status
echo ERRORLEVEL: $?
```

And the log from the Java application. Note the errorlevel being returned as 0 at the end:

```
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:xxx, moduleName:xxx-ejb-generic, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.xxx.EJBClientInvocationContext@50a638b5
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:727)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:183)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:253)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:198)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at org.xxx.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.evalWorkflowStatus(Unknown Source)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at xxx.ejb.workflow.test.ClientAsyncComStrategy.startWorkflow(ClientAsyncComStrategy.java:83)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at xxx.ejb.workflow.test.yyy.startWorkflow(yyy.java:219)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - at xxx.ejb.workflow.test.yyy.main(yyy.java:132)
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - 
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - null
2016/08/22 20:00:22 - Start XXX (stdout) - ERRORLEVEL: 0
```

Thanks in advance for any hints you can give me!

Comment: `$?` return the exit status of last executed command. In above script, `ERRORLEVEL` variable actually giving the return status of command `echo $status`, and as it is getting successfully executed, it returns "0". If you want to capture the exit status of JAVA then switch the position of last two `echo` commands

Comment: `echo ERRORLEVEL: $?` actually prints the return value of `echo $status`. This echo statement terminates without error, so in the last line `$?` will be `0`. Try to switch those two lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `echo` command sets its own status:

```
echo $status
echo ERRORLEVEL: $?
```

If you want to retain it, you should save it into a variable:

```
rc=$?
echo $status
echo ERRORLEVEL: $rc
exit $rc
```